# Changes to PHP DomNode nodeName behaviour

Tags: php, xml

There appears to have been a subtle (and as far as I can see - undocumented) change in behaviour in the value of nodeName between v5.3 and v5.4.

In v5.3 the name returned did not include the namespace, however, in v5.4 the name includes the namespace prefix.  I'm not sure whether the change is due to PHP or libxml but I don't see anything in the changelogs for either.  I'm also not clear as to precisely at what point the change happened but I'm seeing the before and after effects with 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 and v5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2.

Does anyone know when/why/how this happened?  The change has broken some server software that I've released so I could do with better understanding the change so that I can workaround it efficiently.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: [Here are some pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/) :p

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `DOMNode::nodeName` depends on which subtype that node is.

For a `DOMElement` it is the tag-name: [`DOMElement::$tagName`](http://www.php.net/class.domelement.php#domelement.props.tagname).

The `nodeName` holds the qualified name, so this is with the prefix in case it is set.

If you get a different value for that *DOMElement* subtype this would qualify a flaw because it violates the standard DOM model.

[See it in action.](http://3v4l.org/FHZ4m#v500) (Many different PHP Versions, no changes from PHP 5.0.0 up to 5.5.0beta2)

Comment: This is identical code run on two Ubuntu servers both with standard packages but from the last two releases (Quantal Quetzal and one Precise Pangolin).  When I evaluate the response I get ns:tagname from the latest but just tagname from the earlier version.

Do you know if this is likely to be a PHP or libxml problem?  I mean - who should I complain to!?!

Comment: See the following example which outputs the libxml version as well: http://3v4l.org/6AiYc - As this does not change with those versions there, check on your system which version you're using. It's hard to say what causes the issue exactly because I can not reproduce it.

Comment: DOM Model ref is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-node-nodename and then here: http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-element-tagname

Comment: M8R-1jmw5r - thank you for your help.  But... I'm rapidly going a little insane.  The simple test you point to does indeed produce the same results on 3v4l.org and on my two machines.  However, I'm still seeing differences in my real code!  I've cut it down to the simplest form possible that still shows the difference on my machines. I've uploaded this code http://3v4l.org/NcJvG#v500 but 3v4l.org says they evaluate the same.  Must be some subtle difference on my two machines but I have no idea what it could be! Help! Please! Before I'm carted off to the funny farm!

Comment: I've not got to the bottom of why my machines were behaving differently, but I have solved my problem.  They are handling poorly formatted XML differently.  Once the XML is corrected, then they behave as expected.  My original code was failing to include the namespace declarations in the XML snippet that my code was reading.  Thank you M8R-1jmw5r for getting me there.